# update score information in app

Tags: iphone

I have started my first iphone app an applciation containing rugby games and results for a local competion.  I have put the team and reuslts data in NSArrays.  Can anyone tell me how I can update/refresh the NSArrays with the final scores of matches and also update the team points table.

Regards
John

Comment: Your question is unclear and too vague. Are you asking how to update data in an NSArray?

Comment: Sorry if my question is vague however I am new to all of this.  Actually Bogatyr reply is what I was looking for if I have an NSArray containing Team A vs Team B, then another NSArray contianing Team A Score - Team B Score, I am wanting to update the score information.  I think the idea of updating this in a webpage and then having the app read the information on the web page sounds great.  Are then any examples of this around?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your unclear question is asking "How do I alter the contents of an NSArray"...

NSArrays are immutable, which means once you've created them the objects in them cannot be removed, nor can new objects be added. **However,** nothing is stopping you from altering the actual contents of one of those objects.

So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
  NSArray *scoreDetailsArray = // ... make the array

  ScoreDetails *scoreDetails = (ScoreDetails *)[scoreDetailsArray objectAtIndex:1];
  scoreDetails.score = 7;
```

There is also a type called NSMutableArray in which you can add and remove objects at will. Check out the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a web site that contains all the data from the matches and returns it in XML or Apple property list (a form of xml that you don't have to parse), and read this web site from your application, building your nsarray from the data from the web.

Comment: Hey Mister downvoter: my answer is correct given my interpretation of the question -- hardcoding results into a sports app is usually *not* what people do.

Comment: Sorry if my question is vague however I am new to all of this. Actually Bogatyr reply is what I was looking for if I have an NSArray containing Team A vs Team B, then another NSArray contianing Team A Score - Team B Score, I am wanting to update the score information. I think the idea of updating this in a webpage and then having the app read the information on the web page sounds great. Are then any examples of this around?

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray`s are immutable (read-only).  If you use `NSMutableArray`, you can change its contents.  See [the class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details on which methods are available to you for doing this.

Comment: I think he wants to update objects in the array, though, rather than adding new objects...